# Update DataGrid cell if other cell changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a View that displays a Part. All parts contain a list of identifiers. In my View I display Part Properties and a DataGrid with all the Identifiers of that part.

Now if I change a value of an identifier, I want another value update to the default. But if I change my identifier value and set the default of the other property - my DataGrid does not update. Only if I click on the cell, then it gets updated after losing focus.

How can I update the View automatically?

I guess the problem is that I do not want to update a direct property of the Part, but a Property in a List that is a property of the Part.

View

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Company">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox x:Name="CompanyEditComboBox" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Companies}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Company, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                           SelectionChanged = "CompanyEditComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>


    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CompanyType">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="CompanyTypeEditComboBox" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.CompanyTypes}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding IdentificationCompanyType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdentificationCompanyType, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

View Code-Behind

```
private void CompanyEditComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (PartViewModel)DataContext;
    var box = (ComboBox) sender;
    var c = (Company) box.SelectedItem;
    vm.SetDefaultCompanyType(c);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public void SetDefaultCompanyType(Company c)
{
    SelectedIdentification.IdentificationCompanyType = c.DefaultCompanyType;
    OnPropertyChanged("IdentificationCompanyType");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question here, so when you select a different  `Company` it then should select default `CompanyType` in the selected row of your `DataGrid`?

Comment: great, now if the `CompanyType` is not changed from default it would be saved as the default one. If you only rely on the actual text of the combobox then it's an easy fix but if you require the whole object then you need to set the underlying `SelectedItem` of that ComboBox otherwise when you want to save it will use the `Binding` value. If that makes sense?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use a PropertyChanged event handler in your ViewModel on the `IdentificationCompanyType` property to set the DefaultCompanyTime anytime it changes? When going back to debug WPF applications, I find it easier if all my change logic is in one place rather than spread out in the UI like you have here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. I had to add a

```
OnPropertyChanged("IdentificationCompanyType");
```

into the setter of the `IdentificationCompanyType` in the `Identification` class. After that it got automatically updated in the DataGrid.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should mark it as answered.